# How to make Xcode remember my private git repositories password?

Tags: xcode, git, ssh

I am running a private git repository on my virtual private server and have my Xcode project linked to it via ssh:
ssh://username@myhost.com:999/home/username/Repository.git

How can i make Xcode remember my password?
I tried entering the password in the Xcode settings/accounts/repository and in the ssh url itself. 
Every time I open Xcode it asked me for the password.

Is there any way to make Xcode remember the password?

EDIT:
This is the solution, Thanks to Zaph

Run these two lines in terminal:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat ~/.ssh/*.pub | ssh user@host.com -p 22 'umask 077; cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup SSH keys without a password on your development Mac in "~/.ssh". Add the public key to your server "~/.ssh/authorized_keys".

Initially login with ssh and insure your Mac is added to the server known hosts: "~/.ssh/Known_hosts".